# NOT deleting the existing content of the file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I'm trying to write multiple ArrayLists to a text file. However, it keeps overwriting to the existing content. I want to keep the existing content of the text file and keep adding ArrayLists to it.
Here is my code:

```
public static void writeText(String outputFile, String[] array) {
        Path file = Paths.get(outputFile);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file)) {
            for (String aVal : array)
                writer.write(aVal + "\r\n");  // Note addition of line terminator 
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.err.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    } // end writeText
```

I think using path is the problem because it empties the existing file.
Any suggestions on how to fix this

Comment: Use append options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the append option

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file,
                              StandardOpenOption.CREATE, 
                              StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method newBufferedWriter(Path, OpenOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
  StandardOpenOption)
I keep getting this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I now face a problem where it does not create a text file anymore! It only appends to an existing text file. Is there a way I can create a text file and append to it

Answer (score 1):

DO this in your code:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(logFile,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND))
```

**`StandardOpenOption.APPEND`** ensures files is open in append mode

Comment: Hi, I now face a problem where it does not create a text file anymore! It only appends to an existing text file. Is there a way I can create a text file and append to it

Comment: what do you mean by create a text file anymore? and you are also saying.. it is appending to the text file... cant understand.. statements are contradicting

Comment: I'm trying to write a method to create a file and then append to that file

Comment: Oh then instead of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` just add `StandardOpenOption.CREATE`

Comment: editing main code answer as well... dont blame yourself.. its a learning process